# >> operator in Python

Tags: python, operators

What does the `>>` operator do? For example, what does the following operation `10 >> 1 = 5` do?

Comment: And this stuff is really useful for example in such way you can faster multiply 2 by some big numbers.If you want to multiply 2 by 16 (2 * 16 = 2 * 2^4) all you need to do is to shift 4 bits to the left. 2 * 16 == 2 << 4 == 32

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's the right bit shift operator, 'moves' all bits once to the right.

10 in binary is

1010

shifted to the right it turns to

0101

which is 5

Comment: note: in this example it moves them once because of the '1' on the right side of the bit shift operator.

Comment: Does this mean right shift halves the number if shifted to right ?

Comment: @Kishan: No. This one happens to halve it because it's a shift of one on a number that is alternating 1 and 0. Do some tests with numbers that you convert to binary. You'll see the correlation.

Comment: Well... a right shift does half the number for each step, but it rounds down. (Pretty much the same as "moving a decimal point to the left in a decimal number means dividing by 10", but you lose what is after point, rounding down). ------- A left shft, on the other hand, means doubling (compare to moving a decimal point to the right: means multiply by 10)

Answer (score 23):

`>>` and `<<` are the **Right-Shift** and **Left-Shift** bit-operators, i.e., they alter the binary representation of the number (it can be used on other data structures as well, but Python doesn't implement that). They are defined for a class by `__rshift__(self, shift)` and `__lshift__(self, shift)`.

**Example:**

```
>>> bin(10) # 10 in binary
1010
>>> 10 >> 1 # Shifting all the bits to the right and discarding the rightmost one
5 
>>> bin(_) # 5 in binary - you can see the transformation clearly now
0101 

>>> 10 >> 2 # Shifting all the bits right by two and discarding the two-rightmost ones
2
>>> bin(_)
0010
```

**Shortcut:** Just to perform an integer division (i.e., discard the remainder, in Python you'd implement it as `//`) on a number by 2 raised to the number of bits you were shifting.

```
>>> def rshift(no, shift = 1):
...     return no // 2**shift
...     # This func will now be equivalent to >> operator.
...
```

Comment: Note that this is not a good idea with respect to performance. `>>` is O(1) in shift, while `no // 2**shift` is O(n) in shift. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6807431

Comment: @lumbric Obviously, as not only do bit-shifts work slightly differently internally but they also have the advantage of being implemented in C. I only gave that algorithm to give an example of it and make how it works clear.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I just wanted to clarify this with my comment. Somebody who is new to programing, might prefer your example for real code without noticing the drawbacks.

Answer (score 6):

You can actually overloads right-shift operation(>>) yourself.

```
>>> class wierd(str): 
... def __rshift__(self,other): 
... print self, 'followed by', other 
... 
>>> foo = wierd('foo') 
>>> bar = wierd('bar') 
>>> foo>>bar 
foo followed by bar
```

Reference: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/122384

Answer (score 4):

Its the `right shift` operator.

`10` in binary is `1010` now `>> 1` says to right shift by `1`, effectively loosing the least significant bit to give `101`, which is `5` represented in binary.

In effect it `divides` the number by `2`.

Comment: When you say it divides by two, you mean two raised to the power of the second operator, in other words, `a >> b == a / (2**b)`.

Answer (score 2):

See section [5.7 Shifting Operations](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/shifting.html) in the Python Reference Manual.

> They shift the first argument to the
>   left or right by the number of bits
>   given by the second argument.