# What is the double inequality (>>) sign in python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - '>>' operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411749/python-operator)

There's some code that does this:

```
x = n - 1 >> 1
```

I don't know if I have to provide more syntax, but what does the >> mean?  I've been searching all over, but can't find any explanation.

Comment: I believe it's bit shifting, same as most other languages

Comment: See [this brief explantion](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) on Python bitwise operators.  Then you'll have enough to start googling.

Answer (score 6):

Its a shift right logical, it is a bitwise operation that tells the number to shift in bits by that amount. In this case you are shifting by 1, which is equivalent to dividing by 2.

If you do not understand bitwise operations, a simple conversion for you to remember would be this.

x >> n

is equivalent to

x // (2**n)

Comment: Surely you mean `x // (2 ** n)`, right?

Comment: @Daniel Pryden Oh gosh, I'm an idiot, thanks so much for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

It is the [bitwise shift-to-right operator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types).

It shifts the bits of the integer argument to the right by the number on the right-hand side of the expression:

```
>>> 8 >> 2
2
```

or illustrated in binary:

```
>>> bin(0b1000 >> 2)
'0b10'
```

Your code example is actually doubly confusing as it mixes arithmetic and bitwise operations. It should use the ['//' integer division operation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) instead:

```
x = (n - 1) // 2
```

Comment: I guess I have some work to do converting integers into binary format.  What is the double // operation?

Comment: @yeenow123: The manual (now linked in my answer) says "(floored) quotient of x and y"; can be translated as floor(x / y); thus `8 // 2` is 4, but so is `9 // 2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
x >> y
```

is equivalent to

```
x.__rshift__(y)
```

which, as others have said, is meant to be a bitshift.

Answer (score 1):

>> is the bitwise right shift operator. This operator move all bits in the first operand right by the second operand.

So: a >> b = a // 2**b

Example:

- 36 in binary is 0b100100
- 36 >> 1 is 0b10010 (last binary digit or "bit" is removed) which is 18
- 36 >> 2 is 0b1001 (2 bits removed) which is 9

Note that the operator goes after addition. So the code does n-1 first, then right shift it by 1 bit (i.e. divides by 2).