# Order of operation in multiple applications of overloaded __le__

Tags: python

In python I am trying to refunction the __le__ operator in order to chain the variables that are "compared" into a list

a > b > c should give [a,b,c]

I have tried to do this but I get some strange behavior depending on whether or not I include brackets between the values being compared.

```
class OpQue:
    def __init__(self,opA,opB):
        self.ops = [opA,opB]
    def __gt__(self,b): #self > b
        #print("gt OpQue")
        if isinstance(b,Operation):
            self.ops.append(b)
            return self
        elif isinstance(b,OpQue):
            self.ops.append(b.ops)
            return self
        else:
            raise ValueError
class Operation:
    def __gt__(self,b):#self > b
        if isinstance(b,Operation):
            return OpQue(self,b)
        elif isinstance(b,OpQue):
            b.ops.insert(0,b)
            return b
        else:
            return ValueError

a = Operation()
b = Operation()
c = Operation()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tmp1 =  (a >  b  > c)
    print(" No brackets: ",len(tmp1.ops))
    tmp2 =  ( (a >  b)  > c)
    print(" Front brackets: ",len(tmp2.ops))
    tmp3 =  (a >  (b  > c))
    print(" Back brackets: ",len(tmp3.ops))
```

Surprisingly for me this gives the following result:

```
 No brackets:  2
 Front brackets:  3
 Back brackets:  3
```

I would expect the no bracket case to be the same as both other ones, what am I missing?

Comment: I think `a > b > c` is parsed as if it were `a > b and b > c`, to allow it to be used for chained greater-than.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case, and the "and" operation is not overloadable. I'll need to think of something new. :\

Comment: may I suggest the [rshift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411749/python-operator) and lshift operators? (As in, overload these, since so few people actually use them for their real purpose.)

Answer (score 0):

Chained comparison operators are treated as if they're done pairwise with `and` between them. This is what allows you to write:

```
if 1 <= x <= 10
```

to test if `x` is between `1` and `10`. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#not-in) says:

> Formally, if *a, b, c, ..., y, z* are expressions and *op1, op2, ..., opN* are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

Overloading the operator doesn't change this special parsing rule.

So when you write

```
tmp1 = (a > b > c)
```

it's evaluated as

```
tmp1 = (a > b and b > c)
```

This sets `tmp1` to the result of `b > c`, which is `[b, c]`.